Exporting Procedural Crowds FBX with textures
Apologies from the start if this is some basic stuff.
I am trying to export a FBX of a crowd using the add-on procedural crowds from Diffuse Studio.
I need to export so it can be imported into D5 as that's the render workflow we're using.
Currently I can get the 3D object exported, but it's just white with no textures. I have tried several youtube video but so far I haven't been able to get it to work.
I'm sure it's level 1 of the most basic things to do in Blender, but I'm stuck!
Can someone give me some ideas on things to try?

.fbx export why there are no materials or textures
